# How to build a tabular form or editable interactive grid on an existing page in apex 5.1.3?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Recently our oracle apex application got upgraded to version 5.1.3. Ever since the upgrade, I am having trouble creating a tabular form or an editable interactive grid on any existing page.

I could create an editable interactive grid on a new page and then add other regions to the page. However, I can't seem to do the other way around. I do not see any options to select an interactive grid in either 'Create Form Region' or in 'Create Report Region'.

Here's the list of options I see when I try to create a form region on the current page:

[image]

And for the Report region on the current page:

[image]

And for Form Region on a new page:

[image]

I couldn't find anyone having such issues in any of the forums, which makes me believe that I must be missing something way too obvious. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

References : https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11698.apex-5-1-interactive-grid-compared

Answer (score 0):

Click **Create Page**. In a list of possible options, you'll see the **Legacy Page** at the bottom of the list - choose it. In there, you'll see the "Tabular Form" you're looking for.

**[EDIT]** (as here's much more space to type than in the comment)

I have an old application created back in Apex 4.x. It was **not** migrated to 5.x (currently, I'm on 5.1.1), only Apex was upgraded to a more recent version, while that application runs "as is". I'm writing this because - maybe true "upgrading" makes things different ...

Anyway: I opened that "old" application and went to edit a page that contains a "Static content" region. Then I added a new region. In a list of possible region types, there's the "Show Legacy/Unsupported ..." at the bottom of the list. I chose it; the "Type" list collapses, but when I returned back to it, it shows "Tabular Form [Legacy]".

If I choose it, I get the message saying

This will just create the tabular form and not the associated processes and validations. To generate the related processes and validations please use the Create Page wizard".

Does this help?

Comment: That's right. I can build a tabular form on a new page via a legacy page or by choosing the editable interactive grid, like I shown in the pictures above, simple enough. However, I do not see an option to add a tabular form/ interactive grid on a current working page or an already existing page with regions in it.

Comment: @Blurryface, I edited my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: I am afraid not so much. I went through this approach previously and figured this wasn't going to help me with anything. I was looking for a way to implement a complete working tabular form/interactive grid on an existing page with several other regions already defined. 

Having a tabular form without any DML processes is hardly of any use really. I would rather use IR than 'tabular forms without any processes' to display data. Interactive reports would serve a better purpose for such requirements.

Comment: Yes, I can always create a new page with an interactive grid, but I would need to have the tabular form on a page which already has several reports and items. Tabular forms would be displayed conditionally.

Comment: I figured. I was using Component View to create an interactive grid all this while. I was able to create one the moment I switched to Page Designer mode. 

Thanks for looking into this though!